# Split a string to only use the middle part in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a string

```
ABC - ABCDEFGHIJK - 05/07/2016
```

I want to only use the `ABCDEFGHIJK` section and remove the first and third parts of the string.

I have tried using `SUBSTRING` with `CHARINDEX`, but was only able to remove the first part of the string.

Anyone help with this?

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: Doing a SUBSTRING('abcdef', 2, 3);  would result in the result "bcd". So I dont understand why you are saying that using substring cannot solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `TRIM()` for spaces :

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string_col,'-',2),'-',-1)) AS Strig_Col
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Inner `SUBSTRING_INDEX` should be `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string_col,'-',2)`.

Comment: @10086 - I think either would be fine, but I would normally go with your solution as it copes when extra delimited parts are added to the end.

Comment: Ah, yes. My fault.